# Alternate mount for Kryptonite U-Lock?

Tags: accessories, lock

My wife's bike doesn't have room on the upright to mount the Krytonite U-Lock she was given as a gift. The plastic mounting bracket sticks out way too far. She has a small framed Specialized Vita.

Is there some alternate bracket that can be purchased that would allow it to be mounted via the existing holes in the frame where the water bottle bracket would go?

Comment: I just keep mine around the handlebar stem. It has never been a problem.

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Is this [EZ-Bracket](http://www.amazon.com/Kryptonite-720018310730-EZ-Bracket-Kit/dp/B000NOO40U) what it came with?

Comment: Yes, the EZ-Bracket came with it and doesn't work.

Comment: A picture of the mounting bracket and lock might help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some alternate bracket that can be purchased that would allow it to be mounted via the existing holes in the frame where the water bottle bracket would go?

First, Kryptonite makes more than one U-Lock [(at least 6 models)](http://www.kryptonitelock.com/Products/List.aspx?cid=1001&scid=1000) and more than one mounting. So, my first impulse would be to check the [Kryptonite site](http://www.kryptonitelock.com/CustomerService/Contact.aspx) or inquire at a local bike shop that carries the Kryptonite product line.

Second, Does the lock really need to mount on the frame? If the bike has a rear rack, the lock could get bungeed there. Or perhaps in a pannier? Or backpack/messenger bag? Jersey pocket? And, just sayin, the hipsters around here keep U-locks in their back pockets and that's for fun. ;~)

Not to be rude, but U-locks can be mounted or carried in a few places. Personally, I don't carry the U-lock on the water bottle mounts...mainly since I actually do want water bottles to be on the frame mounts. But hey, it's up to you.

Comment: I asked Kryptonite and haven't rec'd a response after 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Twofish CycleBlock or MegaBlock is a good universal lock holder.

Answer (score 1):

If the bike in question has a rack, you can generally loop bungee cord around it to make u-lock holder that is fast to use and keeps to lock secure in place.